# How to do a conditional join in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two hive tables and I want to do a join only if both the tables have data in them. I don't want the join to happen if one of the table is empty.
I tried exploring case statement with the intention that I would do something like

```
select count(*) as val 
case
 when val > 0 then <do join of table1 and table2 here>
 else
   <do nothing>
end
from table2
```

However it looks like hive wont allow to perform an evaluation within the case statement, so this approach does not work. Anyone has any input on how to perform this in hive.

Comment: you can try left outer join between Table1 and Table2.

Comment: no SQL has this functionality. I would insert your logic into a script: count records of both tables. if both counters>0 do your join

Comment: @rajat A left outer join will still result in the join operation. My need is to completely eliminate join when it is not required

Comment: @user2051590 then i guess you need to break the steps and write the logic as suggested by belostoky into a script and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from TableA as a
left join TableB as b
on b.A_Id = a.A_Id
where
    b.A_Id is not null or
    not exists (select top 1 A_Id from TableB)
```

Here is the [Source](https://forums.asp.net/t/1887910.aspx?Inner%20join%202%20tables%20but%20return%20all%20if%201%20table%20empty) which I came across.